# NBA 7 game playoff series where every game was won by the road team?

Tags: trivia, nba, postseason

I have only ever come across this 5-game series ([1984 ECR1, NJN vs PHI, NJN win 3-2](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_1984_EC1.html#NJN-PHI)), where the road team won every game.

Has this ever happened in a 7-game series?

(In recent memory, one series in which the first 4 games were won by the road team was [HOU vs DAL, 2005, WCR1](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_2005_WC1.html#DAL-HOU). But the next 3 games were won by the home team.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the inception of the NBA through the 2017 Conference Finals, 128 game sevens have been played. Of those, only [26 game sevens have been won by the road team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NBA_game_sevens).

Of those 26 series 5 of those have had 5 road wins, but none have had 7 road wins (6 road wins is not possible for this scenario)

1968 Boston @ Philadelphia [5 road wins](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_1968_EDF.html#BOS-PHI)

1974 Boston @ Milwaukee [5 road wins](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_1974_finals.html#BOS-MIL)

1981 Houston @ San Antonio [5 road wins](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_1981_WCS.html#HOU-SAS)

2005 Indiana @ Boston [5 road wins](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_2005_EC1.html#IND-BOS)

2017 Utah @ Los Angeles Clippers [5 road wins](http://www.basketball-reference.com/)

It is possible that there were 6 road wins in a playoff series and the home team finally won in game 7, but the answer to your question would still be no.

Comment: For clarification, how is six road wins not possible?

Comment: It's possible if the home team wins the final game, but if the 7th game is won by the road team there could not have been 5 previous road wins (because the other win would have also been on the road)

Comment: In either format (2-3-2) or (2-2-1-1-1), the road team **can** win every game. What prevents this from happening? Does home field change based on who wins?

Comment: Yes, I never said the road team could not win every game, but if the road team wins game 7 it's only possible that there were 1, 3, 5 or 7 road wins in the series. You can't have 6 road wins if game 7 is won by the road team.

Comment: That's where I was missing your point. It **can** happen, but not if the road team wins every game. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I think the Bulls/Phoenix series went 6 games and had 5 road team wins.

Comment: @Oldcat looks like you are exactly right ([source](http://www.landofbasketball.com/head_to_head_gl/bulls_vs_suns_game_log_pl.htm)).  Good memory!

Comment: For any future updates, please verify not only the series result, but also the other numbers (number of 7 game series and number of game 7s won by road team, which are fairly easily obtainable [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NBA_game_sevens))