# Has there been a best-of-seven series where all games were won by the away team?

Tags: trivia, postseason, major-leagues

On October 30, 2019, the seventh and final game of the [2019 World Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_World_Series) will be played. It's currently 3-3 and the interesting thing is that so far, the *away* team has always won; the Nationals won the first two games in Houston, the Astros won the next three in Washington and the last game, in Houston, was again won by the Nationals. Playing home is usually considered an advantage; I found an [article](https://bleacherreport.com/articles/1803416-is-home-field-advantage-as-important-in-baseball-as-other-major-sports) claiming that it's not (such) an advantage in baseball as in other sports, but that focuses on *series* instead of single games, and in series the better team is most likely to win anyway.

The Houston Astros may still win the final game on their home turf, but if they don't: would this remarkable feat be a first? Or has there ever been a best-of-seven series where all games were won by the away team? [This answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4567/10583) seems to suggest it never happened in the NBA, but maybe in the MLB or NHL, or another major competition with best-of-seven playoffs?

Answer (score 3):

This, from [MLB.com](https://www.mlb.com/news/world-series-road-teams-notching-early-wins) on October 30, 2019:

> The Nationals’ season-saving 7-2 victory over the Astros in Game 6 on Tuesday night made road teams a perfect 6-0 in this year’s Fall Classic. It’s the first World Series in which the road team has won each of the first six games, and it’s also the first time in 1,420 best-of-seven postseason series across MLB, NBA and NHL in which the road team has won each of the first six contests.

EDIT: on the evening of October 30, 2019, the Washington Nationals won the MLB World Series, making it the only best-of-seven series in the four major sports to have the first 6 or all 7 games won by the road team.